# Contact Types Not Updating in Main Menu

Tags: contacts, menu

When editing or adding Individual and Organization contact types the main menu doesn't update the contact type text. For example the options under Contacts > Individuals > are still New Student, New Parent, and New Staff, when they should be New Member, New Intern, and New Staff. When I click on "New Student" it brings me to add a new member page, so it's really just the menu list that is not updating and the pages themselves are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this and describing it so clearly. I have reproduced this problem on the latest version of CiviCRM, though in my testing I found the problem to be limited to *editing the label of existing contact types* (adding new contact types work okay in my testing).

### Bug

This looks like a bug to me. I would suggest you take this a step further by [filing a bug report](https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting). You can use the text you wrote already and even link to this page too.

### Work-around

In the mean time, if you're still in the process of configuring CiviCRM (and haven't yet created contacts with your desired sub-types), you can delete those problematic sub-types and create new sub-types for "Member", "Intern", and "Staff".