# Contact types not updating

Tags: contacts, configuration

When editing or disabling Individual and Organization contact types, the main menu doesn't update the contact type. For example I disabled Student, Parent and Staff for Individual. The options under Contacts > Individuals > are still New Student, New Parent, and New Staff.

I have checked this forum and found that there is already [one question regarding this subject](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20312/contact-types-not-updating-in-main-menu) telling that it is a bug. 
I have upgraded to the very last version (5.17) and have the demo contacts records charged in the CiviCRM instance I use (under WP).

Any idea ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the menu should also be edited in Administer -> Customize... -> Navigation Menu then Delete or Disable the inactive menu items
Sorry for that but documentation should be clearer ;-)

Comment: Documentation is a community project/responsibility and if you can make an improvement that would be wonderful but appreciate there is some time involved figuring the process of making such contributions.

Comment: Agree with you... and I'll think about it